# Click event fired only one time at the first load of the application

Tags: webforms, buttonclick

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms. I fire an JavaScript event to button click. My problem is this event is fired only one time at the first load of the application. It seems that somehow event unbinds of the button. Can anyone help me with that?

Here is the ASPX button control

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetReport" runat="server" Text="Apply"></asp:Button>
```

and here is the JavaScript code:

```
$("#btnGetReport").click(function () {
    var fromDate = $('#txtDateFrom').val();
    var toDate = $('#txtDateTo').val();
    if (fromDate != "" && toDate != "") {
        GetReport(fromDate, toDate);
    }
    else {
        alert("\"Date From\" and \"Date To\" fields are required");
    }
});
```

The first time I click the button, it fires .click() event. but next clicks don't fire anything.

Comment: Please post the relevant code to reproduce the problem, preferably as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise probably nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `UpdatePanel`?

If the answer is yes, then you need to bind the click event on page load and after `UpdatePanel` update.

```js
$(function () {
    var _initialize = {
        ReportBindClick : function () {
            $("#btnGetReport").on('click', function () {
                var fromDate = $('#txtDateFrom').val();
                var toDate = $('#txtDateTo').val();
                if (fromDate != "" && toDate != "") {
                    GetReport(fromDate, toDate);
                }
                else {
                    alert("\"Date From\" and \"Date To\" fields are required");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Bind on page load complete
    _initialize.ReportBindClick();

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        // Bind after UpdatePanel update
        _initialize.ReportBindClick();
    });
}
```